# Google Kubernetes Engine: Enable HTTPS for Service type

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops

I have an application on GKE that I wish to be available via HTTPS only, so I have gotten a signed certificate to secure the application using TLS.

I have checked out a lot of tutorials on how I can do this, but they all refer to using Ingress and automatically requesting the certificate using, LetsEncrypt and KubeLego. But I wish to continue using the external load balancers (the compute engine instances that google has provided me) but I just want my application to be accessible via https.

How do I apply my server.crt and server.key files to enable https.Do I  [apply it to the Load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates) or to the kubernetes cluster.

Comment: May be You wanna take a look at this open source project. https://github.com/appscode/voyager

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ingress is probably your best bet when it comes to exposing your application over HTTPS. The Ingress resource specifies a backend service, so you will to continue exposing your application as a Kubernetes service, just with type set to `ClusterIP`. This will produce a service that is "internal" to your cluster, and will be externally accessible through the Ingress once you set it up.

Now, specifically in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), any ingress resources defined in your cluster will be served by a Google Cloud Load Balancer, so I don't think you have to worry about deploying your own Ingress Controller (e.g. Nginx Ingress Controller).

In terms of TLS, you can use your own certificate if you have one. The certificate must be uploaded to the cluster through a Kubernetes Secret. Once that secret is defined, you can reference that secret in your Ingress definition. (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls)

You can create the secret using the following command:

```
kubectl create secret tls my-app-certs --key /tmp/tls.key --cert /tmp/tls.crt
```

Once you have your secret, you can reference it in your ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-app-certs
  backend:
    serviceName: s1
    servicePort: 80
```

Once you have created your ingress resource, GKE will configure the load balancer and give you a publicly accessible IP that you can get using:

```
kubectl get ingress my-app-ingress
```

The following is a good tutorial that walks you through Ingress on GKE: 
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Comment: thank you very much, i have done this and used the default nginx service to test but I expect it to indicate that the site is secure in the address bar but it does'nt. Does this procedure indicate the site is secure?

Comment: @Ogbe That will be much harder to figure out through this communication method. How did you obtain the cert? Is it trusted by your browser? Is the certificate being served? Does the DNS name match up the name (or names in SANs) in the certificate?

Comment: BEWARE: Kubernetes secrets are stored in PLAINTEXT on etcd, and any node with access to the APIserver can access any secret even if not assigned. Take appropriate care! https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#risks

Comment: As of Kubernetes 1.7, encryption at rest can be enabled to encrypt secrets: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/

Comment: I awarded the bounty to this answer, I have been able to install the ssl certificates but I need to route all http request to https, setting the ssl_redirect annotation to true and allow https annotation to false has not helped in achieving this

Answer (score 3):

Ingress is the easiest way. You do not need to use LetsEncrypt, you can specify your own certificate.

Ingress controller is just an NGINX proxy. If you don't want to use an ingress (why?) you'll have to create this proxy service yourself. Which will essentially be the ingress for this one service.

Comment: does using ingress mean I have to create a new load balancer?

Comment: A load balancer is created for every service of type LoadBalancer (every externally exposed service.) The idea is to have a single ingress and all you other services should be internal.

Answer (score 2):

**The solution:**

Fetch your certificates during runtime, lots of people use LetsEncrypt because of how easy it is but you can store your certificates in an actually secure storage such as your cloud platform's Key Management Store, or run your own Hashicorp Vault (I recommend Hashicorp Vault, it's *very* good!) and then retrieve your secrets securely at runtime.

---

You noted that every tutorial or guide recommended to fetch them dynamically.

> but they all refer to using Ingress and automatically requesting the certificate using, LetsEncrypt and KubeLego.

The reasoning for this is as follows:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#risks

> Risks
>
> In the API server secret data is stored as plaintext in etcd; therefore:
>   Administrators should limit access to etcd to admin users
>   Secret data in the API server is at rest on the disk that etcd uses; admins may want to wipe/shred disks used by etcd when no longer in use
>
> A user who can create a pod that uses a secret can also see the value of that secret. Even if apiserver policy does not allow that user to read the secret object, the user could run a pod which exposes the secret.
>
> If multiple replicas of etcd are run, then the secrets will be shared between them. By default, etcd does not secure peer-to-peer communication with SSL/TLS, though this can be configured.
>
> Currently, anyone with root on any node can read any secret from the apiserver, by impersonating the kubelet. It is a planned feature to only send secrets to nodes that actually require them, to restrict the impact of a root exploit on a single node.

Therefore everyone is correctly recommending that you **DO NOT USE K8s SECRETS** for storing your valuable certificates as it is NOT FIT for the job.

Comment: This is indeed another way of doing it. But just to be clear, as of Kubernetes 1.7, encryption at rest can be enabled to encrypt secrets: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/