# What's the easiest way to create an HTTPS endpoint on Kubernetes?

Tags: python, ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt

I've created a simple Python API using [responder](https://github.com/taoufik07/responder) and deployed it to Google Cloud with Kubernetes. I don't have a domain name just a raw IP address.

```
http://192.0.2.42/api/myapi
```

And deployed as:

```
kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      192.0.2.1     <none>         443/TCP        5d15h
web          LoadBalancer   192.0.2.100   192.0.2.42        80:32749/TCP   5d15h
```

and

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-pod-name   1/1     Running   0          16h
```

I'd like to make it an HTTPS endpoint so I can use it as:

```
https://192.0.2.42/api/myapi
```

But I am struggling to find the easiest way to do it.

Should this be something that is done via Kubernetes, or something that is done in the Python code? It doesn't look like responder  provides an easy mechanism for this.

Comment: I would suggest with Ingress and let's encrypt https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/secure-kubernetes-services-with-ingress-tls-letsencrypt/

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi That seems very involved. Does an "ingress" replace a "service" or do both need to be in place?

Comment: Ingress maps an url to a service https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress link specific to gcp, let me see if we can get ssl via service in gcp

Comment: Using IP addresses in HTTPS URLs is not a good idea. Instead of fighting for that to work just buy any domain name and use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48532318/3514300

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2043645/3514300

Comment: Cool I have a domain now too @PatrickMevzek

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the bare minimum level of effort to do this, you'll need to install an SSL certificate inside your docker container. You can also continue to use **externalIP** as you are now.

Then in responder you can enable HSTS to redirect http to https.

`api = responder.API(enable_hsts=True)`

Then just access your pod with

`https://192.0.2.42/api/myapi`

Comment: I did see that option, but I don't think has provisions to use SSL certificates. I can't see anything in the docs. I also asked here: https://github.com/taoufik07/responder/issues/391